# Kivy KivyMD - How to use multithreading to fill up different MDgridLayouts within MDTabs

Tags: multithreading, kivy, kivymd

Python 3.6.4 - Kivy 1.11.1 - KivyMD 0.104.1

I'm fairly new with Kivy and kivyMD, and even more with threading and shared resources.

Today, I fill in the 3 MDGridlayouts (sbgridfamily, sbgridgender, sbgridspecies) sequentially with SmartTileWithLabels. It works fine, however the loading time is quite long (~5 sec.).

To optimize this loading, I tried

1. to split the loads in different threads, without using a lock or a
   semaphore, some cells end up empty.
2. to remove the MDGridlayouts from the structure and create them on
   the fly in one thread, then I get an assertion error as soon as I add the first tile to
   a MDGridlayout.

   ```
   _apply_rule assert(rule not in self.rulectx)
   AssertionError
   ```

So what would be the best approach to build the MDGridlayouts in parallel?

The screen has the here below structure:

```
<Screen>
BoxLayout:
    orientation:'vertical'

    MDToolbar:
        title: 'Titre'
        ...
    
    MDTabs:

        Tab:
            text: "Famille"

            ScrollView:
                id: sbgfscrollview
                do_scroll_x: False

                MDGridLayout:
                    id: sbgridfamily
                    ...
        Tab:
            text: "Genre"

            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_x: False

                MDGridLayout:
                    id: sbgridgender
                    cols: 3
                    ... 

        Tab:
            text: "Esp\u00E8ce"

            ScrollView:
                do_scroll_x: False

                MDGridLayout:
                    id: sbgridspecies
                    cols: 4
                    ...

    # Will always be at the bottom of the screen.
    BottomAppBar:
```

[Screen with first tab and gridlayout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdyIj.png)

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Specifically, the multi-threaded code.

Comment: Hi John, I understand your request however I cannot provide a code that no longer exists. It was not working as expected, I deleted it to revert to the previous version.
For reproducibility I would have to provide a dataset extracted from the sqlite database and the photographs used.
A lot of work for an application that I develop as a dilettante (hobby).
Thank you for taking the time to read my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6.4 - Kivy 1.11.1 - KivyMD 0.104.1

My problem was the creation and loading time of about 300 thumbnails with on-the-fly resizing of the images, if they were missing from a cache.

In order to optimize, without using threads, I will redirect my next development towards loading galleries at least one page for each tab (50 thumbnails) using Clock.schedule_once when starting the application, then page by page on demand, using the on_scroll_start and on_scroll_move scrollview events.

After a quick try, with this approach, the screen appears in less than a second the first time, then it's immediate.